# QXmlStreamReader only returns one element

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qfile, qxmlstreamreader

This is the xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Text>alpha beta</Text>
<Text>beta gamma</Text>
<Text>gamma delta</Text>
<Text>delta epsilon</Text>
<Text>epsilon golf</Text>
```

And this is my reader:

```
QXmlStreamReader inputStream(&dataFile);
        while (!inputStream.atEnd() && !inputStream.hasError())
        {
            inputStream.readNext();
            if (inputStream.isStartElement())
            {
                QString name = inputStream.name().toString();
                if (name == "Text")
                {
                    qDebug()   << "text:" << inputStream.readElementText();
                }
            }
        }
```

And my qDebug only prints:
text: "alpha beta"

Why does it only return one value and how can I correct this?

BR

Comment: That's not valid XML. XML must have exactly one top-level element. Wrap the `Text` elements in some other tag to make it valid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Frank correctly noted in the comment, a valid XML document can only have one root element. Once, you fix the data file content, it will work, but I am providing all the content I used during the testing on my machine, anyway.

#### test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextList>
<Text>alpha beta</Text>
<Text>beta gamma</Text>
<Text>gamma delta</Text>
<Text>delta epsilon</Text>
<Text>epsilon golf</Text>
</TextList>
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>

int main()
{
    QFile file("test.xml");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        qDebug() << "File open error:" << file.errorString();
        return 1;
    }
    QXmlStreamReader inputStream(&file);
    while (!inputStream.atEnd() && !inputStream.hasError())
    {
        inputStream.readNext();
        if (inputStream.isStartElement())
        {
            QString name = inputStream.name().toString();
            if (name == "Text")
            {
                qDebug()   << "text:" << inputStream.readElementText();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
text: "alpha beta" 
text: "beta gamma" 
text: "gamma delta" 
text: "delta epsilon" 
text: "epsilon golf"
```